# If all the characters of an string are unique then print Yes otherwise print No

Tags: python-3.x

If all the characters of an string are unique then print Yes otherwise print No

input:- ABCDGH
output:- YES

input:- AABBCD
output:- NO

input:- AaAbB
output:- NO

Comment: `print(len(set("ABCDGH")) == len("ABCDGH"))`

Comment: Is it case sensitive? should `"Aa"` print Yes or No?

Comment: Yes it is check examples

Comment: Examples don't provide an answer to that

Comment: Check the last input :) it should output "NO"

Comment: @BlueSheepToken because there is "A" twice, that doesn't say about the case...

Comment: @Tomerikoo You are right, my bad ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use set.

```
if len(set(w.upper())) == len(w)): print("yes")
else: print ("no")
```